# How To Set Protractor Specs Using Command Line Arguments Without Using Grunt Or Other Task Runner

Tags: protractor

How can I specify which spec file to run in protractor using command line arguments without using grunt or any task runner?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `--specs` command-line argument:

```
protractor protractor.conf.js --specs='specs/run-just-this-spec.js'
```